# After edit stay on the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a ajax call, like this:

```
function buttonClick() {
       $.ajax({
           type: "Get",
           url: '@Url.Action("GetOrigineelTemplate", "EmailTemplate", new { area = "Salaris"})',
           //data: { EmailContent: "value" },
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           //dataType: "json",
           success: function (response) {

           }
       });
   }
```

And the action method, like this:

```
  [HttpGet]
        [AutorisatieFilter(Rol = "Beheer | Email templates@Lezen")]
        public ActionResult GetOrigineelTemplate(int id = -1)
        {            
            var model = new EmailTemplateModel();

            model = EmailTemplateService.GetEmailTemplate(Context.Klant.Id, Context.Klant.LogoIDSpecified ? Context.Klant.LogoID : 0, id);

            return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());

        }
```

But after I press on save(opslaan) it goes back to the index view.

And it doesn't stay on the edit page(current page).

So my question is:

how to stay on the current page?

Thank you.

Comment: Why using `return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());` if you want to stay in same page?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
    [AutorisatieFilter(Rol = "Beheer | Email templates@Lezen")]
    public ActionResult GetOrigineelTemplate(int id = -1)
    {            
ViewBag.PreviousUrl = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        var model = new EmailTemplateModel();

        model = EmailTemplateService.GetEmailTemplate(Context.Klant.Id, Context.Klant.LogoIDSpecified ? Context.Klant.LogoID : 0, id);

        return Redirect(ViewBag.PreviousUrl);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The action method in your controller is :
`return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());`

So of course you're being redirected to another page.
In order to stay on the same page you need to return something like a string (a result code for example).
Hope it helps.